# Бинарное дерево. Найти минимальный путь между листьями и удалить центральную вершину пути

Tags: c++, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Требуется найти минимальный путь между листьями и удалить центральную вершину этого пути Если центральную вершину определить невозможно - удалить любую из двух возможных.

Что-то совсем нет идей как это реализовать. Опишите, пожалуйста, как бы вы решали данную задачу, наведите на мысль. Код не обязательно

Для пояснения сути прилагаю рисунок.

[image]

После того как определены самые минимальные пути между листьями, нужно определить ближайшую к центру вершину и удалить ее. В случае рисунка это 10||12 && 26||27

Comment: Поясните подробнее, что такое "центральная вершина пути", или уточните правильные ответы. Насколько я знаю, [центральная вершина для пути с чётным количеством вершин не существует](https://acm.bsu.by/wiki/Бинарные_поисковые_деревья). А вы приводите ответ 10||12, т.е. 2 центральные вершины для пути 8-10-12-11?

Comment: @cppquestions, добрый вечер. Да, меня тоже смутил этот момент. Преподаватель сказала, что ее устроит удаление любой из двух вершин, наиболее близко расположенных к центру, в случае четного их количества. Такое вот странное условие. Что посоветуете сделать?

Comment: Каким образом должно быть представлено дерево? Каким образом задаются вершины для поиска пути? На рисунке как-будто изображено упорядоченное дерево. В тексте про упорядоченность ни слова не сказано. Так упорядочено дерево или нет? Почему в вопросе нет всей этой информации????

Comment: @AnT, приветствую вас. Вы правы, дерево на рисунке действительно является BST. Других параметров, указанных вами, в условии нет.

Comment: Ну то есть суть задачи заключается именно в том, чтобы правильно удалить вершину из BST. То есть после удаления BST должно остаться корректным BST.

Comment: @AnT Да, все верно.

Comment: @Ant. Прошу прощения, что ввел вас в заблуждение. BST вовсе не обязательно оставаться корректным после удаления вершин. Имеет значение лишь удаление вершины. Предвосхищая ваш вопрос - я не представляю зачем, но таково мое задание. BST если я верно понял, нужно для того чтобы запилить асимметричное дерево, дабы было что решать. Еще раз извиняюсь за этот инцидент.